# Adding button to controlgroup in jquery mobile header

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, header

I am trying to add two buttons to `controlgroup` dynamically. The `controlgroup` is contained within the `header`. I want the two buttons to be side by side on the right side of header.

But the buttons are getting added in `vertical` way and also there is a rectangular box around the buttons. How can I do it in correct manner?

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/saQFx/1/

```
$('div[data-role="controlgroup"]').append('<a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" id="open-panel"></a>');

$('div[data-role="controlgroup"]').append('<a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" id="open-panel2"></a>');

$('#open-panel').button();
$('#open-panel2').button();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, your setting of `data-type="horizontal"` is getting erased when you try to dynamically push `a` tags into the `controlgroup`. SO i tried setting those values again through code like this :

```
$('#ctrl').controlgroup({
  type: "horizontal",
  corners: false
});
```

Then, `trigger` a create on the `page`:

```
$("#frontPage").trigger('create');
```

This seems to work. I'll look more into this and get back to you. But for now, here's a working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/saQFx/3/

**Changes made**

- removed the data-role from html and initialized `controlgroup` from JS
- changed `append()` to `html()`
- added `trigger('create');` at the end.
- removed `button()`. This ain't needed anymore. If you're doing a lot of changes together, like you're doing now,its wiser to call `create` on `page`.

An alternative though would be to inject the entire control group with all its contents through javascript, then run a `trigger('create')` on your page.

**EDIT**

Unfortunately, when you init `controlgroup` through the JS way, the rounded corners aren't kicking in by themselves. Guess you have to add `ui-corner-all` class by yourself to this, I just didnt want to get into that. That's a whole new level of mess. SO, instead of that, you could try the second method I mentioned:

- injecting the entire control structure through JS itself
- trigger the `create` method of `page` in the end.

Here's a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/saQFx/8/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But why is there a square border around the button? When you add a button outside the controlgroup, there is no border around the button. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/saQFx/6/

Comment: @passionateCoder Its looking fine but not exactly like the button outside the controlgroup. I think controlgroup adds the borders.

Comment: Yes it does. you will never get a perfect circle if your using `controlgroup` because the two elements combine in the middle

Comment: @AndroidDecoded please mark this as the correct answer if you think this has helped you. :-)

Comment: @passionateCoder See the new jQuery doc explaining dynamic control group http://www.uglymongrel.com/jqm/touch/demos/examples/controlgroups/dynamic-controlgroup.php